# Why is $x$ always a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

In the following equation: $$5 F_n^2 \pm 4 = x,$$
where $F_n$ is a Fibonacci number, and the $\pm 4$ shall be treated as $+4$ for even $n$ and $-4$ for odd $n$.

Now, if the above requirements are satisfied, then why is $x$ always a perfect square? Is there a proof for the equation? If so, could I please know how to prove the equation? Also, are there any ideas which would investigate the above equation and why is $x$ always a perfect square?

[Edit: It was found that the $\sqrt{x}$ are Lucas numbers. But how could this be proved using only the LHS?]

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: I don't understand how to go about that. And i also want to know why you have to use $\pm4$ depending on if n is even or odd. Would induction help in understanding that. And could you point me in a direction on how to use induction on this question. (fairly new to induction)

Comment: Well, *TRY* it.  Prove $5F_3^2 +4$ is a perfect square and try $5F_3^2 - 4$ and *see* what happens.

Comment: But how about for the general case?

Comment: Did you notice that the square roots follow the same recurrence as the Fibonacci numbers themselves?  I am sure that helps the proof.  I'll work some more tomorrow.

Comment: square root of x? Ok thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$F_n =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\phi^n -\varphi^n),$$
where
$$\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \qquad \varphi =\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
Note that
$$\phi \varphi=-1.$$
Then
\begin{align}
5 F_n^2 +4(-1)^n &=(\phi^n -\varphi^n)^2 +4(\phi\varphi)^n \\
&=\phi^{2n} -2\phi^n\varphi^n +\varphi^{2n} +4\phi^n\varphi^n \\
&=\phi^{2n} +2\phi^n\varphi^n +\varphi^{2n} \\
&=(\phi^n +\varphi^n)^2
\end{align}
is actually a square. And the irrational parts of $\phi^n$ and $\varphi^n$ actually cancel each other because of the minus sign in $\varphi$, thus $\phi^n +\varphi^n$ is an integer.

Comment: Damn, I did up-to the 4th line of your working out and got stuck! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a proof which explicitly shows that $\phi^2$ + $\psi^2$ is an integer? And that integar will always be a lucas number right? If so, how could that be proved?

Comment: Let $L_n=\varphi^n +\phi^n,$   Since $x^{n+2}-x^{n+1}-x^n=x^n(x^2-x-1)=0$ for $x\in \{\varphi, \phi\},$ we have$ L_{n+2}-L_{n+1}-L_n=0$ for all $n$. And since $ L_0=2$ and $L_1=1$ we have $L_n\in \Bbb N$  for all $n\in \{0\}\cup \Bbb N$. The sequence $(L_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is called the Lucas Sequence.